# Example of measurable space generating by a collectión $\mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathcal{B}$ is not colsed under intersections.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

There is a $\left(M,\sigma\left(\tau\right)\right)$ meausrable space  with $M$ no discrete **(**$\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ a Borel $\sigma$-algebra where $\tau$ is a topology in $M$**)** such that  $\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ is generating by a collection $\mathcal{B}\subset \sigma\left(\tau\right)$, but $\mathcal{B}$  is not closed under intersections of the any two elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $\mathbb {R},$ consider the collection of open intervals together with the set $\{0,1\}.$